# Ubuntu 14.04LTS Skipping while playing music

Tags: vlc, music, sd-card

I have problem with playing music, doesnt matters what kind of file (mp3, wma, flac). When I listen to music at the specif times in song it just skips. Every time on the same spot, so i was thinking that audio files could be broken somehow... But i dont have this problem on windows. Anybody some idea ?

I have my music stored on SD card, with NTFS. I have had activated bitlocker on that card, but then I switched it off. Could that cause the problems ? I use VLC player, but same problems are also in Rhythmbox and

I will be grateful for some advice.

Comment: If you copy those files on your linux disk does the problem still occur? Second question, if you run `vlc -vvv path/to/audiofile` what is the output while the track is skipping?